# Use a coffeescript create function inside a onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am starting with rails and coffeescript, but I am having a strange issue now.
I would like to create a function called log, which I created like this in my .coffee:

```
log = (message) -> console.log message
```

It it translated to js like this:

```
(function() {
  var log;

  log = function(message) {
    return console.log(message);
  };

  log('Podcast downloader 2000');

}).call(this);
```

If I call the function as I am calling in the example, it works.
but now I want to call it using a onclick="log('avb')

```
<span onclick="log('abc')"/>
```

but the function is not on the right scope, so it doesn't get called.

How do I change my code so I can call the function from the onclick attribute?

thanks!

Comment: Inline event handling is not good practice -- use an `eventListener`. And just hoist the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as suggested by Sterling in the comment section, it's not good practice to use `onclick` but if you really need to do this, place the function in the global namespace

```
window.log = (message) -> console.log(message)
```

in cases like this, it's better to create a namespace for the app and add functions there.

```
@MyNamespace = {}

class MyNamespace.CommonFunctions
  @log = (message) -> console.log(message)
```

Then in your view

```
<span onclick='MyNamespace.CommonFunctions.log("abc")'>
```

This keeps things organized and you don't clog the global namespace.

**LISTENER APPROACH**

A better way to do this is to use event listeners (using jquery).

```
# view
<span class='msg'></span>

# js
log = (message) -> console.log(message)

$('.msg').on 'click', -> log('abc')
```